# VUE CLI different paths for files in 'public' folder

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

My application structure is -
folder -> frontend - folder with the applications
folder -> html -> spa - and this is where I put my app that was built
There are 2 folder in 'spa' - assets and static. In static folder there are files from 'frontend -> public'.

Here is the problem
I need to add an external script, so i put in head of index.html

```
<script src="<%= BASE_URL %>static/js/advert.js"></script>
```

When I have built my app everything is fine, but locally(npm run serve) it has the wrong URL.
I tried to play with `publicPath` in `vue.config.js` and even set it up correctly by ternary `process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'`. On local and built mode the file was fount, but it also has changed all of the routes(links, menu, etc).

Please help me with a work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the solution that I figured out.

In my index.html

```
<script src="<%= BASE_URL %><%= NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'spa/' : ''%>static/js/advert.js"></script>
```